# Procedure that get information from other pages from network

Tags: http, call, bots

How can create a procedure in any programming language that create an iconic call to page and get data from network? An simulator for user standard activity. For example, user every day search on Google some key words and get a list of websites that are close to his search. Is possible this action simulate by program that create a call to Google with standard key words and get the results from network? Also this logic can used in other sites without any hardcore part of code?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But this question is way too broad to provide a proper answer. You will at least need to pick a development language.

Comment: using .net c# or angular is possible?